# Issue when minimizing forms with Charts to System Tray,

Tags: c#, exception, charts, system-tray

I have a form that I minimize to the system tray, by hooking-in to the form_resize event.  All worked well, until I added a Chart to the form.  When the chart is on the form, I would get the following exception:

> Width must be greater than 0px.

The highlighted line is:

```
   this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
```

It took me a bit of time frigging around to work-out what the problem was (including that it was adding the Chart that caused it), but managed to deduce it from very long stack trace messages.  Anyway, I managed to solve it by setting the chart visibility to false before hiding the form.

```
private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FormWindowState.Minimized == this.WindowState)
        {
            //Hide chart to prevent exception
            chtCompliance.Visible = false;
            chtHistory.Visible = false;

            icoTrayIcon.Visible = true;
            icoTrayIcon.ShowBalloonTip(500);
            this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            this.Hide();
        }
        else if (FormWindowState.Normal == this.WindowState)
        {
            icoTrayIcon.Visible = false;
            this.ShowInTaskbar = true;

            //Restore chart visibility
            chtCompliance.Visible = true;
            chtHistory.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

Now... this appears to resolve the problem, but seems to me that this is more of a workaround than a solid solution.  Anyone know of a more elegant way of addressing this problem? (I guess for a start I could dynamically look for all charts, so I don't have to hard-code this into the routine if I add more!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Changing the ShowInTaskbar property has **many** side effects.  It is a "difficult" property, it forces the native window to be recreated since the property affects a window style flag that is  specified when the window is created with CreateWindowEx().  The underlying style flag is WS_EX_APPWINDOW, it has to be turned off to get rid of the taskbar button.  Which forces Winforms to destroy and re-create the window.

That has a knack for causing trouble, particularly for controls that haven't been debugged well enough.  And you *are* doing it at the worst possible time, when the window is minimized and doesn't have a meaningful size.  So sure, such a chart control might well object against being re-hosted to a new window with a 0x0 size.

Short from trying to keep that balky control happy, the much simpler workaround is to just *not* change the ShowInTaskbar property.  There is no point to it, the taskbar button is invisible anyway when you call Hide().

Remove the ShowInTaskbar property assignments to fix your problem.

Comment: Brilliant!  Thanks!  Much more elegant, and I also appreciate the explanation of why the problem is occurring.