# Why is ShowInTaskbar crashing my app with no exception?

Tags: c#, .net

In my code, the following crashes the app running on Windows 10 Professional.

```
this.ShowInTaskbar = true;
```

This has been tested on 2 different machines. There is no exception shown when I include the aforementioned line of code in a try/catch block. There is no exception either when I subscribe to `Appdomain.UnhandledException` event.

There is an application error with `Event ID 1000` in event viewer stating that an error occurred in `System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll` but there is nothing else I can make sense of.

This problem cannot be reproduced on the development machine which runs on Windows 10 Professional also.

The form has no controls except a `NotifyIcon`. After experimentation I figured out that the problem lies on the following lines of code:

```
private void onFormResize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized) this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
}

private void notifyIcon1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        this.ShowInTaskbar = true;
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

If I first change the `WindowState` and then show the form on the taskbar then everything flows OK. Also, if I remove the code from `OnFormResize` the application does not crash either, regardless of the sequence of command execution in `notifyIcon1_MouseDoubleClick`.

Comment: What does your try/catch block look like? It may be swallowing the exception.

Comment: Does it also happen if you create a new windows forms project and just add this one thing? I think that changing `ShowInTaskbar` recreates the window - perhaps you're doing something unsafe with the window? We can't really help you unless you can give us sample code that reproduces the error - setting `ShowInTaskbar` to true works fine.

Comment: @Luaan I have edited the question providiing more details. The problem was overcome though by switching the lines mentioned. It still troubles me why the app crashed though.

Comment: Try attaching to Window StateChanged event instead of FormResize and do the logic there.

Comment: Some background info on the trouble with ShowInTaskbar in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24747958/17034).  Windows 7 adds more trouble by hiding exceptions in an event like this when you forced your program to run in 32-bit mode.  Solution is very simple, just call Hide() instead, that hides the taskbar button as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Disclaimer:* Most of this is non-contractual behaviour, so don't take it authoritatively - different versions and configurations of Windows and .NET Framework may have their own tiny effects on what's happening.

You show the window in task bar. That requires recreating the window, which causes a resize. In the resize event handler, you hide the window in the taskbar. That requires recreating the window, which causes a resize. In the resize event handler, you hide the window in the taskbar - but that doesn't recreate the window, because the "Am I shown in taskbar?" field has actually been updated already. However, it enters the infamous "accessing Control.Handle while creating a handle" infinite loop - that's arguably a bug in the framework (and funnily enough, it happens if the form is minimized or maximized, but not "normal-sized"). `Control.Handle` calls `Form.RecreateHandleCore` which calls `Control.Handle` and you're done :)

Why doesn't this happen on all machines? Because the resize isn't always necessary. This might be related to any number of things - UI themes, font sizes, displays... But the fundamental error is still there - you're causing infinite recursion. It just gets skipped over because you get one less `Resize` event.

Why can't you catch the exception? Well, `StackOverflowException` can be a bit sneaky this way. You're in the middle of security critical code, likely inside a native call, and you get a stack overflow. How exactly do you recover? All the runtime knows is that the stack guard has been hit - for all it knows, someone just replaced half of your program's memory. `OutOfMemoryException` is quite similar - you have no idea how to get to a safe state again, so the only option is to fail fast.

Changing the `WindowState` before `ShowInTaskbar` fixes the problem two ways - one, it changes the way your resize handler works - that's an error in your code, and changing the window state prevents that code (`ShowInTaskbar = false`) from running. The second is that the `Control.Handle` access when the form recreates its handle only occurs when the window is minimized or maximized - that's the framework part. Needless to say, this is quite fragile - and errors like this can be hard to find and fix.

So, what would the proper way of doing this be? You want to hide the window from the taskbar when it's minimized. That's only when the window state used to be non-Minimized, and changed to Minimized - so you need to keep the old window state and check it.

Better, don't mess with `ShowInTaskbar`. It seems like you're making things unnecessarily complex, when all you really want is to hide the window when it's minimized! `Show` and `Hide` will do, don't require full trust, and will not keep the form around in the Alt+Tab menu. `ShowInTaskbar` is intended for applications that have multiple windows that are connected somehow - e.g. a modal dialog shown on top of a different form, a multi-window interface that has the same z-order etc. If you just need to hide the form, hide it. No need to keep creating and destroying all the window handles :) I suspect the only reason why the Framework designers gave us the `ShowInTaskbar` property is to give decent support in the designer - but you shouldn't really change it after a form is created; a given form is either shown in taskbar, or it isn't. No reason to change it at runtime.

Comment: Amen!! That was a great answer!!